# Create pthread in order of execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am using C++ and pthread for multithreding. I want execute thread in order of creation Call.

```
retrnThread=pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,&HandleNotifications,(void*)Status);
```

In my application above code executes 3 to 4 time in very quick time and thread executes in Random order. I want to make thread execution in same order as created.

```
retrnThread=pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,&HandleNotifications1,(void*)Status); 
retrnThread=pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,&HandleNotifications2,(void*)Status); 
retrnThread=pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,&HandleNotifications3,(void*)Status); 
retrnThread=pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,&HandleNotifications4,(void*)Status);
```

Execution Order should be:
HandleNotifications1
HandleNotifications2
HandleNotifications3
HandleNotifications4

Here all threads are independent of each other. I do not need to join or sync them.

Comment: _"I do not need to join or sync them."_ If you want to execute the threads in a specific order you have to.

Comment: What's the point of creating 4 threads if they can't run at the same time? Just create one thread that handles the notifications in order (if you need a thread at all).

Answer (score 0):

> In my application above code executes 3 to 4 time in very quick time and thread executes in Random order.

That's normal behavior, as soon a thread is created it's left to the operating system in which order it is scheduled next time.

> I want to make thread execution in same order as created.

You may use a  counting semaphore that is used in all threads and let them wait for a particular counter value.

Answer (score 0):

I am more accustomed to the C# async / await / Task<> Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP) and *I still need to understand if / how C++ can achieve the same functionalities*.

We could imagine something like this (*imagine the "main" function is launched by another external thread* )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

using namespace std;

void handlenotification(int i = -1)
{ 
    cout << "Task number " << i << endl;
    //Long treatment here
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        async(launch::async,handlenotification,i);
    }

    cout << "Bye!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result is ( no interlaced strings )

```
Hello world!
Task number 0
Task number 1
Task number 2
Task number 3
Bye!
```

But it does not give back the control to the calling thread ( Bye! is at the end )

We would have to build something more complicated to achieve this (*by deferring the async call this time* )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

list<future<void>> task_list;

void handlenotification(int i = -1)
{
    //standard output thread safety omitted for example !!
    cout << "Task number " << i << endl ;
    this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(i));
}

void naive_background_worker(void)
{
    while(true)
    {
        //Thread safety omitted for example !!
        if ( !task_list.empty())
        {
            task_list.front().wait();
            task_list.pop_front();
        }
        else
        {
            //naive
            this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(50));
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    //standard output thread safety omitted for example !!
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    for (int i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        //Thread safety for list omitted for example !!
        task_list.push_back(async(launch::deferred,handlenotification,i));
    }

    thread back_worker = thread(naive_background_worker);


    cout << "Bye!" << endl;

    back_worker.join();

    return 0;
}
```

the result is ( no thread safety for cout here !! + never ending background worker)

```
Hello world!
Bye!Task number
1
Task number 2
Task number 3
Task number 4
```